Is setCallbackFunction necessary for OAuth1 authorization?
I’m implementing OAuth1 authorization in GAS, and as of October 31, 2024, I’m wondering if .setCallbackFunction('authCallback') is truly necessary for the OAuth1 authorization method.
Here’s how I’ve set up the method to test its necessity:
OAuth1.createService("twitter")
    ...
    .setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')

I defined a callback function, but I haven’t seen the “Allow this app to connect?” prompt during the initial authorization. I’ve also removed the .setCallbackFunction('authCallback') line and reauthorized without encountering any errors:
const authCallback = (request: GoogleAppsScript.URL_Fetch.CallbackRequest): GoogleAppsScript.HTML.HtmlOutput => {
    const service: OAuth1.Service = getXService();
    const authorized: boolean = service.handleCallback(request);

    if (authorized) {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('success');
    } else {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('fail');
    }
};

I also tried using reset() to clear the authorization and start fresh, but I still don’t see any prompt asking for permission to connect.
Here’s a query about whether the authCallback function is truly required for OAuth1 in Google Apps Script (GAS).
If you are aware of any articles or resources that clarify:
I’d appreciate any insights or resources on this topic!
Alternatively, if there’s a different way to reset the authorization effectively, could you please share that method?
Additionally, I deleted the redirect URL registered in the developer tools for X, yet the authorization still passed successfully.

Yes, callback URI is required for 3-legged oauth1.0a flow in this specific case. Specifically, the server will send the oauth_verifier token, which is needed for further authentication flow. This is specified in RFC5849 § 2.2,

...To make sure that the resource owner granting access is the same
resource owner returning back to the client to complete the process,
the server MUST generate a verification code: an unguessable value
passed to the client via the resource owner and REQUIRED to complete
the process....

This token is then exchanged for access token, which is sent in all future requests. This verifier token is  used to get the access token by the Outh1.0 library and saved, as shown here, when you call
service.handleCallback(request);

However, once authorized, the server doesn't need to re authorize again, as written in § 4.15

...Servers may wish to automatically process authorization requests
(Section 2.2) from clients that have been previously authorized by
the resource owner.

However, in the specific case of twitter, as written in it's documentation

The user will always be prompted to authorize access to your application, even if access was previously granted.

Therefore, the authorization prompt should always appear in this case. If it doesn't, then the client isn't redirecting to the server in the first place. Which may mean access tokens aren't deleted or you're incorrect in assuming the requests were authorized. You may invalidate/regenerate tokens as written in the documentation to force Oauth flow.
